# How can I Edit user profile using TextFormFields?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting user data from firestore and display it into the textformfields using initialValue. I want to update user profile But whenever I use controller to update these values, it is giving an error. Below I am pasting the code. Please guide me how can I solve this issue ?

```
final emailController = TextEditingController();
StreamBuilder(
                stream: firestore
                    .collection("app")
                    .doc("user")
                    .collection("driver")
                    .doc(auth.currentUser?.uid)
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          initialValue: snapshot.data?['email'],
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            hintText: "Email",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 17.0),
                            suffixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.email,
                              size: 20,
                              color: Color(0xff4BA0FE),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),)
```

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: Can you share the error?